# int cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: arrays

I'm counting all of the specific numbers in an array however I keep receiving the error `int cannot be converted to int[]`.

The variables `val` and `two` have been defined in the program before, so that is not the error.

```
public static int[] removeVal(int[] two, int val)
{
    int count=0;
    for (int a=0; a<two.length; a++)
    {
        if (two[a]==val)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Remove the [] in the call after `public static int`

Comment: That's not a 'call'.

Comment: You forgot a very important piece of information - what language are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method returns an array of ints, but you are returning just an int, not an array of ints.

Comment: how do i get it to return just how many iterations of that value is inside the loop

Comment: Just declare it like this: `public static int removeVal(int[] two, int val)`. Instead of returning an array (int[]) now it returns just a number (count).

Comment: but later on in the same method i have to return an array with the all of the "val" removed how would I do that

Comment: You are already returning something from your method. Can't return two things.

Comment: So that would mean to write another method am i correct? and If so would the new method look like this : public static int[] newArray(int[] two, int val,count)

Comment: It would return `int[]`, yes.

Comment: but now when i write that method it says <identifier> expected

Comment: `public static int[] newArray(int[] two, int val, int count)`, put `int` before `count`.

Comment: Thank you Cecilio for your help!

Comment: Sorry for being such a drag but, when I try to call the method like this:: System.out.println("new array with all of the 7s removed = "+Arrays.toString(ArrayFunHouse.newArray(two,7,3)));                                                      An error occurs saying cannot find symbol

Comment: My answer explains why the author is getting the error he is getting: int answers his question.